# Bottom Sheet dont appear , Staying behind the ArFragment in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, arcore, sceneform

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.project.testapplication.WritingArFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_upward_white_24dp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet"></include>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this part is my ui interface action_main.xml and I want to add 3D object in scene that I choose. For that I decide to use modal bottom sheet. I click button and open it the nested scroll view than I choose object and it's go down again. But when I click the up FAB button nested scroll view stay behind the fragment(Java part is working good), therefore it is not appear on screne. I am using ArFragment (ar.sceneform:plugin1.6.0). I dont find where is my fault. Thanks :)

```
FloatingActionButton openBS = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.up);

        View nestedScroll = (View) findViewById(R.id.nestedScroll);

        mBottomSheetBehaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(nestedScroll);

        openBS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mBottomSheetBehaviour.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            }
        });
```

this is MainActivity.java

Comment: Try adding elevation to the bottom sheet. Sometimes elevation causes this issue.

Comment: Take it out of the nestedScrollView that isn't necessary for a bottomSheetView. The only reason to include a nestedScrollView would be if you nest a recyclerView inside a bottom sheet as the scrolling interaction gets eaten by the bottom sheet, but that's hacky as well since it is not optimized. NestedScrollViews turn children into static drawn resources so a recyclerview is pointless inside of them, but that's besides the point.

Answer (score 0):

please follow this tutorial for bottom sheet which is perfectly working

https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/

Comment: thanks for your sharing :) but bottom sheet is working well. I am trying to use it with ARCore ArFragment. therefore bottom sheet dont appear

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem while working with navigation view. Indeed the menu appears but behind the fragment. You can try android:elevation